# FTP will not accept a requested login

Tags: 20.04, vsftpd

I get the following error message when I try to connect to my vsftpd server:

> There was a problem connecting to your host or proxy. Please check your server settings and try again. If you are sure you have entered the correct information, please contact your network administrator or the server administrator. [7] Additional information: couldn't connect to host.

Comment: can you give us more detail? is the ftp server on you local network? do you have any means to verify it is operational? is the computer you are trying to connect to your ftp server on the same network? or internet?  can you ping your ftp server? is there anything we might need to know, like if there is port forwarding on the server or you are using a proxy? what client are you using? Please post as much detail as you can.

Comment: I have a stand-alone Ubuntu Server running on a machine alone. I am trying to connect with a Windows desktop client. They are both on the same private network. I believe it is a permissions problem, but don't know how to troubleshoot it. I'm not sure how to tell if it is actually operations. Is there a way to test it from a FTP client on the server machine?

Comment: Here is something I found googleing for configuring ftp on ubuntu: [config_vsftpd](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-setup-ftp-server-with-vsftpd-on-ubuntu-20-04/)  I'm not familiar with vsftpd, so I can't speak to its accuracy, but perhaps a starting point.

Comment: One way to test if it's the local client or the server is to try another client...  Or use your client to connect to another server.  I guess it's a problem with your server settings?

Comment: @DavidKingsella, please add the details to the question. extended comments aren't the place for us to try and solve problems. you can test your vsftp server from your server, if you wish. there are many means of doing this. you can try it via a browser, or from the command line. when you say Ubuntu Server, I'm not sure if you mean Ubuntu Server OS, or an Ubuntu desktop running a Service.  either way, you can test the ftp server from the command line. `ftp user@ip`
do you have a firewall on your server? is the ftp port open?  is the service running? `ps aux | grep ftp`